# how to check if a user is logged in from another webapp using spring security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

i have the following setup.

server1: i am using spring security v3.1.4 in one application. this application is running on its own server (e.g. tomcat at server1.mydomain.com).

server2: i have another 3rd party web application running on a different server (e.g. tomcat at server2.mydomain.com). this applicaton is pluggable in that it allows me to install jars to dynamically modify behavior at runtime. its purpose is to serve content.

users and resource access are managed on server1. content is delivered by server2. on server2, if a resource request comes in, i need to ask server1 if the user is logged in. is this possible to do with spring security? i imagine i would pass in the username with the resource request (e.g. http://server2.mydomain.com?getFileId=1&username=johndoe@gmail.com).

i read a little bit on the spring security website and SSO seems to be the way to go (e.g. using Central Authentication Service). but that seems like an overkill. our architecture already has several servers running.

- integration (e.g. the webapp using spring security)
- media (e.g. the 3rd party webapp)
- elastic search (a cluster)
- mysql (a cluster)

if possible we would like to have a minimalist system (but our system isn't small, given our investments and assumptions using rdbms/IR clusters).

any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to implement similar approach.But I am new to spring-security could you please help me to achieve this.
I have some doubt, how second application will get security context  or it will create new one based on username/password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of achieving this - although it's not something I've tried myself - could be to expose Spring Security's `SessionRegistry` in server1 via a simple REST based controller. That would then allow server2 to remotely query authenticated users in server1 by making a simple HTTP GET request.

It's probably worth having a read of the [Session Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) section of the Spring Security docs to determine how to access the `SessionRegistry`. The basic setup I think is to specify a `<session-management>` tag inside the `<http>` section of your config on server1.

```
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry"/>
</security:session-management>

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>
```

You would also need to add a listener to the `web.xml` of server1

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The controller that you would need to create on server1 could then be autowired with the `SessionRegistry`

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry
```

From there, you can use `sessionRegistry.getAllSessions()` to determine whether a username (principal) passed in a request to the controller is logged in on server1.

More of an idea than a concrete answer - but may give you an avenue to explore.